# Is it possible to Create Title and Description for dynamically generated pages?

Tags: seo, local-seo

Is it possible to Create Title and Description for dynamically generated pages which are generated automatically by clicking on the certain option of the page and that page generated after it.. please tell me how to add title and description to those automatically generated pages?

Comment: Do you mean the meta description and title for sections within a Single Page App?

Comment: No I mean to say that the automatically generated pages in the dynamic website... Can I give a title description to it?

Comment: If you are dynamically generating the page, then of course you can have the same generation spit out a dynamic title and description.   You don't say how you are generating the page, so it makes it very hard to give you helpful instructions for the title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Provided the team that built this site has given this functionality. Each content thats dynamically generated is shown from a database or some such storage mechanism. This content is usually managed and edited through a Content Management System (CMS). As long as the CMS has such a functionality implemented, it can be done.